# Getting error in query using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am getting the following error inside my query using MySQL.

> Error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'pr.pro_Id=p.pro_Id JOIN db_supplier AS s
>   pr.supplier_id=s.supplier_id JOIN db_or' at line 1

I am explaining my query below.

```
 SELECT
 pr.pro_data_id,pr.pro_Id,pr.specification,pr.Discount,pr.Offer,pr.unit_cost_price,pr.unit_sale_price,pr.quantity
 AS
 total_quantity,pr.shipping_charge,pr.product_code,pr.policy,pr.supplier_id,pr.latest_sale_price,pr.pro_status,pr.sale_price,p.Product_name,s.user_name,op.order_id,op.quantity
 AS
 ordered_quantity,op.final_price,op.prod_tot_price,op.delstatus,op.status,o.order_date,o.shipping_id,sh.name
 FROM db_product_data AS pr JOIN db_product_info AS p
 pr.pro_Id=p.pro_Id JOIN db_supplier AS s pr.supplier_id=s.supplier_id
 JOIN db_order_products AS op pr.pro_data_id=op.pro_data_id JOIN
 db_order AS o op.order_id=o.order_id JOIN  db_shipping_address AS sh
 o.shipping_id=sh.shipping_id WHERE pr.pro_data_id='63' AND
 pr.pro_Id='36' ORDER BY pr.pro_data_id DESC
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **missed ON many times** in your query:-

```
SELECT
pr.pro_data_id,pr.pro_Id,pr.specification,pr.Discount,pr.Offer,pr.unit_cost_price,pr.unit_sale_price,pr.quantity
AS total_quantity,pr.shipping_charge,pr.product_code,pr.policy,pr.supplier_id,pr.latest_sale_price,pr.pro_status,pr.sale_price,p.Product_name,s.user_name,op.order_id,op.quantity
AS ordered_quantity,op.final_price,op.prod_tot_price,op.delstatus,op.status,o.order_date,o.shipping_id,sh.name
FROM db_product_data AS pr 
JOIN db_product_info AS p ON pr.pro_Id=p.pro_Id 
JOIN db_supplier AS s ON pr.supplier_id=s.supplier_id
JOIN db_order_products AS op ON pr.pro_data_id=op.pro_data_id 
JOIN db_order AS o ON op.order_id=o.order_id 
JOIN  db_shipping_address AS sh ON o.shipping_id=sh.shipping_id 
WHERE pr.pro_data_id='63' AND
pr.pro_Id='36' ORDER BY pr.pro_data_id DESC
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Missing `ON` -

```
JOIN db_product_info AS p ON pr.pro_Id=p.pro_Id
```

Comment: In early days in my career I did this database contain 8 Millions records forgot ON and query multiply 8 million * 8 million what happened all servers was close site down for 15 minutes ... :)

Answer (score 2):

try this query **Join table_name ON**

```
SELECT pr.pro_data_id,pr.pro_Id,pr.specification,pr.Discount, pr.Offer,pr.unit_cost_price,pr.unit_sale_price,pr.quantity AS total_quantity,
pr.shipping_charge,pr.product_code,pr.policy,pr.supplier_id,pr.latest_sale_price,
pr.pro_status,pr.sale_price,p.Product_name,s.user_name,op.order_id,op.quantity 
AS ordered_quantity,op.final_price,op.prod_tot_price,op.delstatus,op.status,o.order_date,
o.shipping_id,sh.name FROM db_product_data AS pr
JOIN db_product_info AS p on pr.pro_Id=p.pro_Id JOIN db_supplier AS s on 
 pr.supplier_id=s.supplier_id 
JOIN db_order_products AS op on pr.pro_data_id=op.pro_data_id JOIN db_order AS 
o on op.order_id=o.order_id JOIN  db_shipping_address AS sh on o.shipping_id=sh.shipping_id WHERE  
pr.pro_data_id='63' AND pr.pro_Id='36'  ORDER BY pr.pro_data_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

`ON` operator is missing in all JOINS of your query

```
SELECT pr.pro_data_id,pr.pro_Id,pr.specification,pr.Discount,pr.Offer,pr.unit_cost_price,pr.unit_sale_price,pr.quantity AS total_quantity,pr.shipping_charge,pr.product_code,pr.policy,pr.supplier_id,pr.latest_sale_price,pr.pro_status,pr.sale_price,p.Product_name,s.user_name,op.order_id,op.quantity AS ordered_quantity,op.final_price,op.prod_tot_price,op.delstatus,op.status,o.order_date,o.shipping_id,sh.name 
FROM db_product_data AS pr JOIN db_product_info AS p ON pr.pro_Id=p.pro_Id 
JOIN db_supplier AS s ON pr.supplier_id=s.supplier_id 
JOIN db_order_products AS op ON pr.pro_data_id=op.pro_data_id 
JOIN db_order AS o ON op.order_id=o.order_id 
JOIN  db_shipping_address AS sh ON o.shipping_id=sh.shipping_id 
WHERE pr.pro_data_id='63' AND pr.pro_Id='36' ORDER BY pr.pro_data_id DESC
```